Whats the difference between asyncio and multithreading in python?
Multi-threading
import threading

def heavy_computation():
    # A CPU-bound task
    result = sum(x * x for x in range(10**6))

threads = []
for _ in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=heavy_computation)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

Asynchronous python
import asyncio

# Define an asynchronous function (coroutine)
async def async_task(name, duration):
    print(f"Task {name} started, will take {duration} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)  # Simulate a long-running I/O-bound task
    print(f"Task {name} finished.")

# Define the main coroutine
async def main():
    # Create multiple tasks using asyncio.create_task()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(async_task("A", 2))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(async_task("B", 3))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(async_task("C", 1))

    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    await task1
    await task2
    await task3

# Run the main coroutine
asyncio.run(main())

What are the differences between using multi-threading in Python and Asynchronous Python since the global interpreter lock prevents parallelism of threads, only a single thread can execute at one time. Asynchronous Python is also also single threaded. I suppose, it could the resource management of multi-threads which could make asynchronous python more efficient. Which is preferred for backend applications like Django?
Googled  but no answers

Your two examples are very different. Long cpu bound tasks may not be a good fit for asyncio, especially if short or I/O bound tasks are intermixed. Suppose my I/O takes 20 short interactions but is not responsive because long tasks intervene. As for a backend, you wouldn't want to use asyncio unless that model is supported by the backend stuff you call.
